# Input type Date does not reflect changes

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

The input component works when the input type is other than date.
What I mean is, when I interract with the inputs, for example, input of type text, the `onChange` function updates the input values, and i can see what i have typed.
But when it is a calendar(type date), the value on the state side changes, but the change does not reflect on the screen. The date displays always the same date.
I would like to know where did I go wrong with the below code.
Im using reactjs as a framework.

```
// Input component
export const Input = ({ name, type, required, onChange, value, disabled }) => {
  return (
    <input
      name={name}
      type={type}
      id={name}
      required={required}
      onChange={onChange}
      value={value}
      disabled={disabled}
    />
  );
};

// Input being used in a form component
<Input
  name={input.name}
  type={input.type}
  id={input.name}
  required={input.required}
  onChange={onChange}
  value={input.value}
  disabled={input.disabled}
 />

// inputs
export const inputsFields = [
   {
    id: 5,
    name: "birthday",
    type: "date",
    label: "Birthday",
    required: true,
    value: "2023-01-01",
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    name: "telephone",
    type: "tel",
    label: "telephone",
    required: true,
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    name: "mail",
    type: "email",
    label: "email",
    required: true,
  },
]
```

When I delete the initial value `value: "2023-01-01"` of the birthday field, and i change the date, it works fine(it reflects the change on screen), but i need that date as intial value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add a defaultvalue field in input.

```
// Input component
export const Input = ({ name, type, required, onChange, value, disabled }) => {
  return (
    <input
      name={name}
      type={type}
      id={name}
      required={required}
      onChange={onChange}
      value={value}
      defaultvalue={value}
      disabled={disabled}
    />
  );
};
```

It should work